# Need if statement condition that checks if vimeo video is playing

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

This is my code so far but my condition is wrong and I'm not sure what to use. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function timeout(){
    setTimeout(function()
    {


  if( froogaloop.api('paused')==false)
  {
      document.getElementById('subs').innerHTML = js_arr[i];
              i=i+4;
            j=j+4;
            hour = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(0,1));
            min = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(3,4));
            seconds = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(6,7));
            mil_sec = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(9,11));
            time = (hour*3600000)+(min*60000)+(seconds*1000)+mil_sec;


            timeout();
     }
      else{
        timeout();
      }


    },time);
```

}

Comment: Why don't you take a [look at the documentation](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api)? There's an example there on how to check for messages from the player. Look for `playProgress`.

Comment: Show your full code. And where `froogaloop` is declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS API uses postMessage, so it's asynchronous. You also need to pass the iframe to the API library.

```
$f(iframe).api('paused', function(isPaused) {
    // do stuff here with the isPaused var
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I figured this out a while ago. This was my first question and I'm not quite sure if I should have mentioned later that my problem was solved.